# Issue with patching Jboss to upgrade to version 7.0.5

Tags: jboss

Issue with patching Jboss to upgrade to version 7.0.5

i receive below conflict message while applying patch:

{"message" => "Conflicts detected","conflicts" => {"misc" => ["bin/standalone.bat","bin/standalone.conf","bin/standalone.conf.bat"],"modules" => ["sun.jdk:main"]}}

and if i override the conflicts and try to run my application it runs loginpage but throws error while encrypting password which was working fine in 7.0.4 version.

Any help suggestion would be really appreciated !!!

Comment: This means you modified your installation prior to the patch, i.e. changed a variable in `bin/standalone.conf.bat`, a dependency in the `sun.jdk` module, etc. It would probably be possible to extract these changes to files in your standalone/domain to avoid this problem in the future, but at worst you can reapply them in the installation after having patched with `--override-all`.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks for the reply!. I am new to patching, so could you provide a more elaborate statement corresponding to your response?

Comment: The patch provides new versions of some files of the JBoss EAP installation, but when you apply it, it realizes that the original files were modified. It can overwrite them (which you do when using `--overide-all`), but then these modifications are lost. In your case it looks like these modifications are necessary for the good working of your application, so you should put them back after applying the patch. Moreover, these modifications should be implemented in the configuration files of your domain/standalone or deployment to avoid this problem in the future

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion  @Aaron. 
but now i am getting below error while doing log in to my application:


11:57:19,190 ERROR [stderr] (default task-7) Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider

2018-01-02 11:57:19,190 [default task-7] ERROR stderr - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/net/ssl/internal/ssl/Provider

could you please help with this ?

Comment: Have you identified the modifications that were done to your 7.0.4 installation and reproduced them into your 7.0.5 installation after having applied the patch with `--override-all` (or any other way to transfer your 7.0.4 installation's customization) ? Otherwise I feel like you would have the exact same problem on an out-of-the-box 7.0.4 and that someone working on your project with much better insight in your application and platform needs than I have has already solved this problem and you ought to get in touch with him

Comment: Anyway your error reports that your application server is missing an SSL provider, which makes me think that you must have modified system modules or that your deployment is set up to ignore them, since JDKs provide their own SSL providers AFAIK.